# Can we configure the Redis server to accept LogShippers from different machines?

Tags: redis, logstash

Can we configure the Redis server to accept LogShippers from different machines?

If so then how and for the redis-client what could be done.

Any help will be highly appreciate!  Regards//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Redis can accept data from different shippers. Just use the same shipper configuration on each server.

If you are shipping lots of data to Redis, you will need to tweak the Redis configuration for high loads. For instance, you may need a replica node.

Once your data gets through Redis to Elasticsearch, you can query it with Kibana. Searching on the @source_host tag will allow you to isolate logs from different servers.

Be careful when setting up multiple Redis/ElasticSearch stacks on the same network. If 2 ElasticSearch servers have the same cluster name, they will form a cluster (without your intervention). If you then shut one of them down, your cluster will degrade.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure Redis server.
All you need to do is to make sure it can accept connection from the logstash server. 
For example on Amazon it is called `security groups`. Or if you installed it yourself, look at `iptables`

In Logstash all you need to do is to make an output filter that will send events to the desired server. Take a look at logstash documentation: http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/outputs/redis